# Remove odd digits in a number

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that removes the odd digits from a number
but when I try 1001,
the result is "all digits were deleted". 
How can I change it so the result is "00"?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  long long int n;
  int digit, o = 0, i = 1;
  cin >> n;
  while (n != 0)
  {
    digit = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    if (digit % 2 == 0)
    {
      o += digit * i;
      i *= 10;
    }
  }
  if (o == '\0')
    cout << "All digits were deleted"
         << "\n";
  else
    cout << o << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is basically correct. When you remove all the odd digits from 1001 you end up with 0. The message that the program gives for that case is a bit misleading, since only two digits were removed in this case, and two were kept.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the test `o=='\0'` should just be `o==0`. And naming a variable `o` is not a good idea; it's easily misread as 0, which can lead to a great deal of confusion.

Comment: When you delete all odd digits from 1001, then the correct result is " 00 ", i.e. blank-zero-zero-blank. In order to store that so that it is different from "0", you have to use multiple chars instead of a single integer. Well actually this is not the answer, I just write it to provoke you into rethinking input, storing and handling "digits". Another way to achieve that would be to ask you what result would you expect when removing all **even** digits from 1001? If you can't answer, then it is probably time to ask your teacher.

Comment: This may be easier by treating the number as a string.  A digit can be converted to a number:  `int digit = number_as_text[i] - '0';`  You can use the `std::string::erase` method to remove digits.  You could use `number_as_text[i] % 2` to determine if the digit is odd or even.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- character codes for digits are required to be contiguous and increasing, which is why `number_as_text[]i - '0'` works. But `'0'` is not required to be even, so `number_as_text[i] % 2` will not necessarily tell you that a digit is even. To check odd or even you need the **value** of the digit, hence, `(number_as_text[i] - '0') / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works. But I guess you want to see the digits, even, if they are 0. Therefor you must store the number as string.

Then you can simply use the existing replace function to get your desired result.

Very simple. Nothing more to explain.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    // Get the users number
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::string number{}; std::cin >> number;

    std::cout << std::regex_replace(number, std::regex("[13579]"), "");

    return 0;
}
```